# Convert a positive number to negative in C#

Tags: c#

You can convert a negative number to positive like this:

```
int myInt = System.Math.Abs(-5);
```

Is there an equivalent method to make a positive number negative?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse

Comment: 280Z28: That is equivalent to myInt = -1.

Comment: has to be   myInt |= int.MinValue;

Comment: @280Z28: That only works for odd numbers, otherwise it's the same as making the number negative, and then subtracting 1.

Comment: For code clarity, I don't think you should use System.Math.Abs() if you want to just "convert a negative number to positive". Mathematically, that's not what Absolute Value is, even though you get the desired result. Depending on your algorithmic context, you should use the solution you've accepted below for going from negative to positive too.

Comment: @Charles, if you don't want to account for negative numbers, you can negate the number with `(myInt = ~myInt + 1)`. The way you have it is simply `(myInt = myInt - 2147483647 - 1)` for positive numbers (negative unchanged), which is about as useful as the one I put in the first comment. :) For floating-point numbers, the bit manipulation like you have does work.

Comment: @280Z28,  What I wrote is not 'negating' the number, It is intended to be the equivilent of minus the Absolute value of the number, which is different. negating a negative would result in a positive.  I assumed the questioner wants to gernate a negative from any number positive or negative...

Comment: "Convert a positive number to negative" is not the same as asking for a negative equivalent of `Math.Abs`, and the accepted answer does not do that either, it just inverts the sign of any number. So you should synchronize 1.Title, 2.Question & 3.Accepted answer.

Comment: do you know the power of minus signal?

Comment: I'm amazed with so many answers for this little question, but shocked by not finding any discus about comparing performance of different solutions!

Answer (score 567, accepted):

How about

```
myInt = myInt * -1
```

Comment: This solution is great because it can also convert negative to positive! Genius!

Comment: I was under the impression you could just simply stick a "-" in front of anything to negate it...   -myInt    This would be the negative of the value in myInt... -ABS(myInt)   would be a garaunteed negative.

Comment: what about `myInt = - Myint` ?

Comment: or even shorter `myInt *= - 1`?

Comment: FYI if you try kokbira's method with a short, `myShort = (short) -myShort` cast is necessary because the short becomes an int when negated.

Comment: Alternatively? ~n + 1

Comment: what about the possibility of an overflow if you use this answer?

Comment: I don't see why this answer was accepted. It's definitely NOT the negative equivalent of System.Math.Abs(...).  
Input -5. While it converts a positive to negative, it doesn't preform as I believe the question originally intended.

Comment: It won't work with long.MinValue, the value still will be negative, unless I have a virus in .NET  :)

Comment: are there any side effects between multiply by (-1) or subtracted by 0?

Comment: myInt = myInt - myInt * 2; yet another

Comment: DOES NOT ALWAYS WORK!!  `int.MinValue * -1 == int.MinValue`

Comment: What is the best way to do this? `myInt *= -1` or `myInt = -myInt`?

Comment: even shorter `myInt = -(myInt);`

Comment: `myInt = myInt * -1` gives the following ReSharper warning `Possible overflow in unchecked context` while `myInt = -myInt` don't.

Answer (score 280):

```
int myNegInt = System.Math.Abs(myNumber) * (-1);
```

Comment: +1 for remembering that if it'a already a negative you'd have the opposite effect.  Your answer is the only one that would always give a negative number regardless of whether the myNumber is positive or negative.

Comment: Only 26 votes for this answer? Are there SO users that think this wouldn't work?

Comment: 30 up votes?
Already the question is so simple. And this over-complicated answer (-System.Math.Abs(myNumber) would also do) gets 30 up votes????

Comment: @rstevens everyone collaboratively trying to indicate this answer is far more correct than the accepted one. Also, - vs * -1 is definitely not "over-complicated".

Comment: I like this answer better than the -System.Math.Abs one, since it is a bit more obvious at a glance what is happening...I think it would be slightly easier to miss the "-" in front of the statement.

Comment: I don't like this. Your code should throw an invalid argument exception if myNumber is negative.

Comment: -1 for not reading the question as specified.  The number is positive.

Comment: Seriously? Using ABS just for changing the sign of a number? In what manner is that better than `int myNegInt = myNumber < 0 ? MyNumber : -MyNumber;`, even if keeping the result always negative was required?

Comment: Beska remarked that it would be slightly easier to miss the "-" in front of the statement. That's happened to me so many times that I enshrined my permanent solution as an integer constant, MagicNumbers.MINUS_ONE, which is readily accessible to all of my code by including a single namespace, WizardWrx, and adding a reference to one library, WizardWrx.Common.dll.

Answer (score 146):

```
int negInt = -System.Math.Abs(myInt)
```

Comment: Yes, because negation is the goal, so a unary minus is the right operator.  On the other hand, multiplying by negative one is just a trick to negate a value.

Comment: It's a trick because it counts on a side-effect, not the primary effect.  The primary effect of unary minus is to negate.  The primary effect of multiplication is to multiply.  It just so happens that multiplying by -1 negates.  Is that clearer?

Comment: @StevenSudit No, not nicer than * -1. Multiplying by -1 is not "a trick" it is the mathematical way to turn a number negative. -Number is just a shorthand of -1*Number. In addition, using Abs for keeping the number negative is an overkill. `myInt<0 ? myInt : -myInt;` is much better. Just because the - operator is provided as a shorthand for the proper -1*Number plus the overloading capabilities, does not make * (-1) a trick.

Answer (score 104):

The same way you make anything else negative: put a negative sign in front of it.

```
var positive = 6;
var negative = -positive;
```

Comment: Everyone forgets the unary minus.

Comment: Whats the practical difference between this and this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348080/convert-a-positive-number-to-negative-in-c-sharp/1348091#1348091  `int myNegInt = System.Math.Abs(myNumber) * (-1);`

Comment: @makerofthings7, the one you linked to is a lot more CPU instructions -- an absolute-value operation (at least [three instructions](http://www.strchr.com/optimized_abs_function) on x86), followed by a MUL (or possibly a NEG if the compiler is clever). This answer is a single, lightweight NEG opcode, nothing more or less than what you need. Of course, the two answers behave differently when the input number is already negative; if (unlike this question) your input might be negative, that makes the decision for you.

Comment: The question that pops up in my mind is what is better at performance level? The minus in front of the variable or multiply it for -1?

Answer (score 45):

Note to everyone who responded with

```
- Math.Abs(myInteger)
```

or

```
0 - Math.Abs(myInteger)
```

or

```
Math.Abs(myInteger) * -1
```

as a way to keep negative numbers negative and turn positive ones negative.

This approach has a single flaw. It doesn't work for all integers. The range of `Int32` type is from "-2<sup>31</sup>" to "2<sup>31</sup> - 1." It means there's one more "negative" number. Consequently, `Math.Abs(int.MinValue)` throws an `OverflowException`.

The correct way is to use conditional statements:

```
int neg = n < 0 ? n : -n;
```

This approach works for "all" integers.

Comment: I'll toss you the point for correctness, but any code that depends on nobody taking the Abs of MinValue is brittle.

Comment: Steven: Sometimes, you are solving a problem (like `Abs`) that can't possibly work for `int.MinValue` (assuming `int` return type.) In that case, it's completely OK to throw an exception. However, this specific problem has a "valid" result for `int.MinValue` but throws an exception if you take the `Abs` route.

Comment: After saying that the negative scale is larger than the positive, you then go and suggest code that does not account for this. If `n` is `-32768` then `-n` is ALSO `-32768` !!! Furthermore `int neg = n < 0 ? n : -n;` cannot possibly work in all cases, as one of the ternaries does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 24):

The easy way:

```
myInt *= -1;
```

Comment: Was about to post the same, everyone should show the *= some love :-)

Answer (score 20):

```
int negInt = 0 - myInt;
```

Or guaranteed to be negative.

```
int negInt = -System.Math.Abs(someInt);
```

Answer (score 12):

To switch the sign of an integer, you just use the sign operator:

```
myInt = -myInt;
```

To make it negative regardless if the original value is negative or not, you first use the Abs method:

```
myInt = -Math.Abs(myInt);
```

Answer (score 10):

I use `myInt = -myInt;`

So simple and easy

If you want to have only positive

```
myInt = myInt>0 ? myInt : -myInt;
```

Comment: I was looking for this answer in a slightly different situation as the OP. I want to have 2 values negate eachother if one of them is -5 the other should be 5, therefor this is my best solution =D

Comment: you would get an overflow since  the `int.MaxValue` is `2147483647`, even `var i = int.MaxValue; i++;` wont work

Answer (score 6):

EDIT:  This is wrong for positive inputs... I made mistake of forgetting that the rest of the bits in -x (2s-Complement value)  are the 'opposite' of their value in +x, not the same.  SO simply changing the sign bit will NOT work for positive numbers.

I'll leave this here for in for purposes...

Or the tricky way ( I think )...

int y = x | ~int.MaxValue;

```
cause int.MaxValue is 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

so

```
~int.MaxValue is      1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

and therefore any int32 Or'ed with that will put a 1 in the sign bit, (making it negative), and leave all the other bits the same...

EDIT:
  actually,  Since the 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 is actually the Minvalue, this should also work:

```
   int y = x | int.MinValue; // or, to do it to itself,
   x |= int.MinValue;
```

Comment: So, negative zero equals int.MinValue?

Comment: No, in twos complement, there is no negative zero.  all ones is negative 1.  A Signed 8Bit Int: 10000000 is -128

Comment: +1 because no one deserves to be downvoted for answering a question like "what letter comes after A but before C?"

Comment: ... and, thanks to @Mehrad's answer below, This is the only approach that works when input is int.MinValue...

Comment: Charles: This is wrong. For negative numbers, it works but for positive numbers, just flipping the sign bit doesn't make `-number`. `1` is all zeros and a one. Or-ing it with `int.MinValue` will result 10000000000000000000000000000001 which is not equal to `-1` (all ones.)

Answer (score 6):

Just for more fun:

```
int myInt = Math.Min(hisInt, -hisInt);

int myInt = -(int)Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Math.Sin(1), 2) + Math.Pow(Math.Cos(-1), 2))
            * Math.Abs(hisInt);
```

Comment: Too risky, IMHO. What if the definition of a circle changes?

Answer (score 6):

Even though I'm way late to the party here, I'm going to chime in with some useful tricks from my hardware days. All of these assume 2's compliment representation for signed numbers.

```
int negate = ~i+1;
int positiveMagnitude = (i ^ (i>>31)) - (i>>31);
int negativeMagnitude = (i>>31) - (i ^ (i>>31));
```

Comment: Care to explain this more? with `i == int.MinValue`, then all the variables are `-2147483648`

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun:

```
int negativeInt = int.Parse(String.Format("{0}{1}", 
    "-", positiveInt.ToString()));
```

**Update**:  the beauty of this approach is that you can easily refactor it into an exception generator:

```
int negativeInt = int.Parse(String.Format("{0}{1}", 
    "thisisthedumbestquestioninstackoverflowhistory", positiveInt.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this?

```
int n;

.... some coding....

n = n<=0? n:0-n;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
long negativeNumber = (long)positiveInt - (long)(int.MaxValue + 1);
```

Nobody said it had to be any *particular* negative number.

Comment: Um, if you don't care that it has to be a *particular* negative number, you could simplify this to "long negativeNumber = -1;"

Comment: @Guffa: that's the joke here, actually.

Answer (score 3):

```
int myInt = - System.Math.Abs(-5);
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiply it by -1.

Answer (score 2):

Converting a number from positive to negative, or negative to positive:

```
public static decimal Reverse(this decimal source)
{
     return source * decimal.MinusOne;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As previously mentioned, just multiplying by -1 is not cool, as `int.MinValue * -1 == int.MinValue`

It really depends on your application, but for mine (Inverting Joystick axes) I want to ensure that all extremes are still reachable, and maintain as much fidelity as possible.
To this end, I map Max <--> Min and everything in-between gets a `* -1`
Using this technique, -32767 is unreachable when inverting.

```
    private static int Invert(int value)
    {
        if (value == int.MaxValue) return int.MinValue;
        if (value == int.MinValue) return int.MaxValue;
        return value * -1;
    }
```

Comment: Invertion to `5` is not `-5`, but `1/5`.

Answer (score 0):

Just something that I want to share.

```
public decimal NumberReevaluate(decimal number, bool isPositive)
{
    var tempNumber = System.Math.Abs(number);
    return isPositive ? tempNumber : -tempNumber;
}
```

Comment: `number >= 0 == isPositive ? number : -number`

Answer (score -1):

Use binary and to remove the last bit which is responsible for negative sign.

Or use binary or to add sign to a datatype.

This soln may sound absurd and incomplete but I can guarantee this is the fastest method.

If you don't experiment with what I have posted this post may look crap :D

Eg for int:

Int is 32 bit datatype so the last bit (32th one) determines the sign.

And with a value which has 0 in the 32 place and rest 1. It will convert negative no to +ve.

For just the opposite or with a value with 1 in 32th place and rest 0.

Answer (score -3):

`X=*-1` may not work on all compilers... since it reads a 'multiply' 'SUBTRACT' 1 instead of NEGATIVE
The better alt is `X=(0-X)`, [WHICH IS DIFF FROM `X-=X`]