# Why does C# Math.Floor() return Double instead of Int

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Math.Floor(Double) return a value of type Double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348892/why-does-math-floordouble-return-a-value-of-type-double)

Why does C# `Math.Floor()` return `double` instead of `int`

From the MSDN Docs:

> Returns the largest ***integer*** less than or equal to the specified double-precision floating-point number

it says it returns an integer. Its ok to return a `double`, I can always cast it to an `int` but its just quite strange, isn't it?

Comment: It is poorly worded. Arguably it should say "whole number" (or something else, even in the notes) to avoid ambiguity with with the *int*eger data-type(s). However, [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) is a mathematical term, so, while confusing here, is technically correct.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not really, considering that a `double` can be a much higher magnitude than an `int`. You wouldn't want to overflow an int with the large value that a double could be.

Just to show you what I mean:

Double.MaxValue = 1.7976931348623157E+308

Integer.MaxValue = 2,147,483,647

So you could have a double that is 3,000,000,000.50 and floor it, which would overflow the max value of an int.

Comment: That's a good explanation for why it makes sense... the explanation why it is that way is much simpler though -- the FPU result is a `double`.  Since many times you want to use it as a `double` (maybe subtract it from the argument, to get the fractional part), it wouldn't make sense to convert it and then have to convert it back.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - Also a good point, but doesn't explain why the returned value could NOT be of Integer type as the documentation verges on suggesting. Just because the FPU outputs something doesn't mean that a method needs to return that result, esp in a non-native runtime environment. The MSDN documentation probably should have used the phrase "integral part" or something like that instead to avoid confusion with the type name.

Comment: if it was a size thing, surely they could just return a long / Int64?

Comment: I agree with @userx and we could also think about the cost of conversion, a integer exist in the double domain and the opposite is not true, so is better to represent a integer as a double then not.

Comment: @mynye - Even an Long / Int64 isn't big enough. MaxValue of an Int64 is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, which is 9E+18. A double can be as large as 1E+308 which is a LOT bigger. The reason for this is that part structure of a double (and singles / decimals) denotes the exponent for a fraction. Doubles and Ints are very different and serve very different purposes. I wouldn't say that it is any better to represent an int as a double as there are may be cases where a double may be less precise (I'm not sure, a double has 53-bits for its fraction, definitely true for a single though).

Answer (score 3):

Because the **INPUT** is a double, the **OUTPUT** must also be a double, or a lot of potential output would not fit into the output variable.

In mathematical terms, the *domain* and the *range* of the function must have the same size.