# C#: How can I make an integer negative?

Tags: c#, operators, integer

How can I make an integer negative in C#?

```
abc = 5645307;
// how to make abc -5645307 ?
```

Comment: num *= -1;    (and some more)

Comment: I'm puzzled - this is such basic math, why was this question asked?!?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a positive number to negative in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348080/convert-a-positive-number-to-negative-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something:

```
abc = -abc;
```

If you want it to be negative whether it was negative beforehand or not, you would use:

```
abc = -Math.Abs(abc);
```

Comment: Skeet's gravitational pull is so massive he just attracts points.  Eventually he will be crushed by their weight into a singularity, at which point we'll be sucked through the event horizon and Jeff will poke his eyes out and scare the bejesus out of everybody.

Comment: @Will: Do you mean Jeff will poke *my* eyes out, or his own?

Comment: you mean it's forming a black hole that has already become a neutron star ? beware Jeff..

Comment: no I mean Jeff will play Sam Neil's role (my comment isn't very funny but its less so if you don't get the reference:  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119081/)

Answer (score 6):

This is how **you** can convert **your** int value to minus in c#

```
abc = abc > 0 ? abc*(-1) : abc;
```

Answer (score 2):

how about....

```
xyz = Math.Abs(xyz) * (-1)
```

Comment: I agree....in that case we would need to do an Abs on that number, i.e. xyz = Math.Abs(xyz) * (-1). Thanks for pointing out....