# How to convert negative number to positive in c#?

Tags: c#

Where taking away a minus value i.e. `5 - (-5)`, we are working this out as 10, which yes, mathematically it is correct.

But in this case, our logic should treat each number as a positive and not minus negative numbers. It should be `5 - (-5) = 0` as per our requirement.

Comment: How about `Math.Abs();`

Comment: @owt Please try to look for the existing answers before posting question.

Comment: @owt Please consider accepting an answer to this question so that it can be closed.

Answer (score 12):

Other people have provided Math.Abs as a solution. I don't know whether this inlines Math.Abs or not... But measure the performance gain from something like this vs Math.Abs:

```
int d = X > 0 ? X : -X;
```

to verify that it's really worth it.

if Math.Abs throws an OverflowException. You can force this in the straight C# as well using checked arithmetic:

```
int d = X > 0 ? X : checked(-X);
```

I ran some quick tests on different methods you can use:

```
Math.Abs(i)                    5839 ms     Factor 1
i > 0 ? i : -i                 6395 ms     Factor 1.09
(i + (i >> 31)) ^ (i >> 31)    5053 ms     Factor 0.86
```

Winner: ([only `int`] as you can't bitshift floating point numbers in C#):

```
public static int ConvertToPositive(int i) { 
    return (i + (i >> 31)) ^ (i >> 31);
}

ConvertToPositive(-5); // 5
```

Comment: This one is the **best solution**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348090/9258504

Comment: @SamBerk No? That simply toggles between positive or negative. The question was about **converting a negative number to a positive**.

Comment: I understand. but toggling between positive or negative includes also converting from negative to positive IMO

Comment: @SamBerk what if a positive number enters the function? Then the output would be negative. So its not the best solution to this question or a valid answer that covers all cases. Multiple operations will also just toggle the value between -/+.

Comment: I get your point.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use [`Math.Abs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ke8e73(v=vs.110).aspx)

You will have to convert every number that may be negative into a positive value like so

```
var result = 5 - (Math.Abs(-5))
```

Answer (score 10):

Try Math.Abs this will solve the purpose.

So before applying any arithmetic operation you should apply Math.Abs(value) which will convert your negative value to positive.

```
class Program
   {
       static void Main()
       {
           //
           // Compute two absolute values.
           //
           int value1 = -1000;
           int value2 = 20;
           int abs1 = Math.Abs(value1);
           int abs2 = Math.Abs(value2);
           //
           // Write integral results.
           //
           Console.WriteLine(value1);
           Console.WriteLine(abs1);
           Console.WriteLine(value2);
           Console.WriteLine(abs2);

        }
    }
```