# Positive and negative number values

Tags: java, c#

What is the best way to switch between a positive and negative value in a statement (in the example of a boolean):

```
myBoo = !myBoo
```

To do the same with an int I would need to check with if statement:

```
if (val >= 0)
{
     val = val*-1
}
else
{
    val = Math.abs(val);
}
```

is there a more direct way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't tag multiple langauges

Comment: Just multiply it by -1!

Comment: Just multiply by -1.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want negative numbers to be positive and positives to be negative... just multiple both by -1

Comment: Please look at this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348080/convert-a-positive-number-to-negative-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to just add a negative sign in front of the value:

```
int myInt = -myInt;
```

Another way to switch between a positive or negative number in a statement would be to multiply it by -1.

```
myInt = myInt * -1;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
int myBoo = 7;

myBoo = -myBoo;
```

Comment: More efficient than multiplication afaik, so +1.

Comment: @PerryMonschau I think in practice that this wouldn't be more efficient, at least measurably so, an interesting benchmark to try out though.

Comment: @DavidG I think this sort of benchmark would come down to the compiler used. Probably most are smart enough to compile both into the same operation, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @PerryMonschau Well I doubt they would compile to the same operation, at least not in C#. I just don't think the difference would be much, if anything.

Comment: @DavidG Different code for different situations. If this operation takes place in the core process of an application and wants to run a million times a second, then every optimisation counts.

Comment: @PerryMonschau Yes, but I'm suggesting that even that won't matter.

Comment: @DavidG like you said, an interesting benchmark to try out.

Comment: @PerryMonschau Well I tried it with 100 million iterations and that gave me a difference of 0.1s in total, second run it was the other way round. So not enough for most mortals to worry about :)

Answer (score 0):

there is a function: `Math.negateExact`.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#negateExact-int-

Answer (score -2):

You can use **Math.signum()**, it returns -1.0 if number is negative and 1.0 if it is positive, 0 if it is zero

Comment: The person asking the question wants to negate the number. so for example given `1234` it would give you `-1234`. This does not answer the question at all.